# Connect overlapping lines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-9.2, multimodal-network

I am currently trying to build my first multimodal network using ArcGis 9.2. This is a test using simple data of what I will need to do later with more complex data.

**Here is my data:**

- layer 1: One shapefile containing a line feature. It's the main road.
- layer 2: One shapefile containing a polyline feature. These are the
  secondary roads.

My problem is that layer 1 has not been created as connected to the features in layer 2 (created as a long line). As a consequence, there is no vertex where two features intersect, they simply overlap.

To be clearer here is a picture:

[image]

The blue line is layer 1, the black ones is layer 2 (all the vertices belong to the feature where they stand).

How can I make to overlapping lines intersect so they can understood as connected when I build my network?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000) tool - that should create the vertices where lines intersect that you are after.

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.